# Cálculo do múltiplo de 10 maior ou igual a um valor

Tags: c#

Utilizar módulo 10;
Exemplo:

```
7  4  8  9  3  1  0  7  2 <== Dados
x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2 <== Peso
=  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =
14 4  16 9  6  1  0  7  4 <= Resultado
1+4=5 1+6=7
//resultado da multiplicação, cujo valor for maior que 10 (dez), os dígitos do resultado devem ser
//somados, resultando um valor menor que 10 (dez);

5 4 7 9 6 1 0 7 4 = 43 <== Resultado Final
//Somatório do resultado das multiplicações = 43
```

Até aqui tudo certo. Agora vem meu problema. Como achar Múltiplo de 10 maior ou igual ao somatório que 43?

Meu código atual:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= soma; i += 10) {
    if ((i % 10) == 0) {
       if (i >= soma) {
          Multiplo = i;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o resultado esperado.

Comment: O valor que você espera encontrar é 50 ?  Não entendi muito bem o que você perguntou.

Comment: isso mesmo, preciso encontrar, 50 veja meu cód.  
for (int i = 0; i <= soma; i += 10)
{
                if ((i % 10) == 0)
                {
                    if (i >= soma)
                    {
                        Multiplo = i;
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Sempre que tiver um código poste para ajudar as pessoas entenderem o problema e até onde você chegou.

Comment: Não é necessário verificar se `i mod 10` é igual a 0, pois você sempre incrementa a variável com 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para encontrar o multiplo de 10 mais próximo, você pode fazer uso do seguinte pseudo-código:

```
int multiplo;
if(quociente % 10 != 0)
{
  int quociente = soma / 10;
  multiplo = (quociente+1)*10;
} else
{
  multiplo = soma;
}
```

A primeira variável vai pegar apenas a parte inteira do quociente da divisão por 10, e então o multiplo mais próximo é o sucessor do quociente multiplicado por 10.

Evitei de declará-las na mesma linha para evitar qualquer problema com declaração simultânea das variáveis, já que uma depende da outra, se a dependência não existe, ocorre erro.

Comment: Bem tinha chegado ao resultado com uma POG, kkk Mas esse seu cód é muito mais enxuto. valeu, Deu certo aqui. Bem agora tenho que calcular o 2º e o 3º campo da linha digital. Af

Comment: Haha, sem problemas.

Comment: @mutlei, parece-me que esta resposta falha quando a soma já é multiplo de 10.

Comment: @JJoao verdade... Corrigindo.

Answer (score 4):

Sei que é antigo mas tem um jeito mais simples....

```
if(soma%10==0){
    multiplo = soma;
}else{
    multiplo = (soma-(soma%10))+10 
}
```

Comment: Porquê o downvote?

Comment: Foi só para registrar mais uma alternativa de calculo.

Comment: @DarioTeodoro, sua resposta é completamente válida. O comentário do ramaral foi direcionado para o usuário que votou negativamente na sua resposta.

Comment: @ramaral Eu não sei o motivo, mas suponho que quem negativou foi porque só apresentou o código, mas não explicou o cálculo, fora que se olharem bem as variaveis tinham (eu editei) acentos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, talvez tenha sido por isso. Não acho que seja razão suficiente, o código é fácil de entender. Além que deve ser levado em consideração o facto do AR ser novo por aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento E que não há problemas em criar variáveis com acento.

Comment: @jbueno não estou habituado ao c#, só comentei isto pois imagino que na maior parte das linguagens a sequencia de caracteres para criar uma variavel seja `[a-z][a-z0-9_]`